# PHP: Color text if returned date difference is longer than X years

Tags: php, datetime, colors

I'm attempting to create a custom member tag for my forum that will display "X Years of Experience" but with different colors for each individual year, such as red for year one, blue for year two, and so forth.

Getting the date difference was simple enough but I'm stumped on the next bit.

This is the code I currently have:

```php
{{$joinDate = $comment->author()->get_joined(); $currentDate = new \DateTime(); $interval = $joinDate->diff($currentDate); $experience = \IPS\DateTime::formatInterval($interval, 1);}}
<li class="ipsType_light">{$experience} {lang="memberexperience_experience"}</li>
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your problem is, can you expand on what the next bit is you are stumped on?

Comment: Sorry. I'm just not sure how to go about doing the IF statement to change the text color based on the output of $experience. To be more specific, I'd like to do something along the lines of "_if $experience <= 1 year **then** set text color_".

Comment: Why don't you use CSS classes to do this? Have the class `member-for-X-years` where `X` is dynamically input from PHP. Then have the classes set the color.

Comment: You can use an array with a structure like `[ years_of_experience => css_class ]` as a mapping (or something similar), to assign appropriate css class to the html element based on years of experience.

Comment: @Mahan_F I thought of using CSS but the output is always "X years/months/day".

Answer (score 1):

I am just trying to give you an idea.

You should create styles.php file in your config folder. And add this below code into this file.

```
return [
  'experience' => [
    1 => 'danger',
    2 => 'secondary',
    3 => 'primary'
 ]
];
```

Then in your blade file write this code

```
<li class="text-{{config("styles.experience.$experience")}}">{{$experience}} {{lang="memberexperience_experience"}}</li>
```

If experience is possible to less than 1 year then use below code

```
@if($experience < 1)
    <li class="text-danger">{{$experience}}</li>
@else
    <li class="text-{{config("styles.experience.$experience")}}"> 
       {{$experience}}{{lang="memberexperience_experience"}}</li>
@endif
```

Hope this will give you an idea and help you.